# Could not find docker-machine in redhat 7.3

Tags: docker, redhat, docker-machine

I am new to docker and have been following the official tutorial: 
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app

I am using `RHEL` 7.3

```
[root@pecan-9A /]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
```

Redhat makes a distinction between their `docker` and `docker-latest` RPMs.  They serve different version of `docker`.  But none of them contains the command `docker-machine` as suggested in the tutorial

```
[root@pecan-9A /]# docker -v
Docker version 1.12.6, build 3a094bd/1.12.6

[root@pecan-9A /]# docker-latest -v
Docker version 1.13.1, build 6774275/1.13.1

[root@pecan-9A /]# docker-machine ip
-bash: docker-machine: command not found

[root@pecan-9A /]# which docker-machine
/usr/bin/which: no docker-machine in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/gradle/bin)
```

Any suggestion where to find `docker-machine` in RHEL?

Comment: For official Red Hat docs about installing and using Docker on RHEL, go to [Getting Docker in RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/single/getting_started_with_containers/index#getting_docker_in_rhel_7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-machine` [appears to be obsolete](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started-cloud/) and was originally [intended for Mac and Windows](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/#what-is-docker-machine).

I think you were expected to run `docker-machine ip` on the host, not on the Linux virtual machine running the containers.

Comment: Thanks! Now I realized in the tutorial they suggest `docker-machine` only for Win7

Answer (score 0):

Download the docker-machine from here on your Red Hat: https://github.com/docker/machine/releases
Use visual studio for editing your file and just keep docker-machine in your workspace. It'll work just fine.